# here.com API credentials failure

Tags: here-api

Solved - answer below

I just signed up for a trial account with here.com, registered an app, and tried using the credentials. I'd used this exact same request before with the demo app id, and credentials but now with the registered trial account credentials it's failing. Any advice? Does it take a long time for the credentials to actually become valid?

```
curl -X GET \
     -H 'Content-Type: *' \
     --get 'https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json' \
     --data-urlencode 'waypoint0=53.011766,-2.224905' \
     --data-urlencode 'waypoint1=53.028236,-2.198126' \
     --data-urlencode 'mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled' \
     --data-urlencode 'app_id=<valid app id>' \
     --data-urlencode 'app_code=<valid app code>' \
     --data-urlencode 'departure=2016-09-10T13:54:29Z' | jsonpipe | less


  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   528  100   528    0     0   2191      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2200
/       {}  
/response       {}  
/response/_type "ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType"
/response/type  "SystemError"
/response/subtype       "SystemError"
/response/details       "These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer representative or submit a request here https://developer.here.com/contact-us to upgrade your account. You can also get valid credentials by registering for a free trial license on https://developer.here.com."
/response/metaInfo      {}  
/response/metaInfo/timestamp    "2016-09-09T14:06:15Z"
/response/metaInfo/mapVersion   "8.30.63.156"
/response/metaInfo/moduleVersion        "7.2.72.0-55447"
/response/metaInfo/interfaceVersion     "2.6.25"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually consistent database somewhere, about an hour later it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue when trying to invoke the weather services from Tibco Rest plugin using invokerestapi activity. Though I was using app_id and app_code generated from the project setup in here site with free plan. This issue got resolved when I used the demo app_id and demo app_code provided in the examples of the same site.